# C program error in MIPS based architecture

Tags: c, mips

This program takes the command line argument and fill write_key array

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

 int main(int argc, char **argv)
 {
   int i,j;
   unsigned char write_key[16];

   for(j=0;j<4;j++){
     for(i=0;i<4;i++){
       write_key[j*4 + i] = (strtol(argv[1+j],NULL,16)>>(8*(4-1-i))) & 0xff;
     }
   }

   for(i=0;i<16;i++){
     printf("write_key[%d] :: 0x%x   \n", i, writekey[i]);
   }
  printf("\n");
}
```

I launch the program with

```
./app 0xffffffff 0xffffffff 0xffffffff 0xffffffff
```

For following input 
output on my linux pc is

```
write_key[0] :: 0xff   
write_key[1] :: 0xff   
write_key[2] :: 0xff   
write_key[3] :: 0xff   
write_key[4] :: 0xff   
write_key[5] :: 0xff   
write_key[6] :: 0xff   
write_key[7] :: 0xff   
write_key[8] :: 0xff   
write_key[9] :: 0xff   
write_key[10] :: 0xff   
write_key[11] :: 0xff   
write_key[12] :: 0xff   
write_key[13] :: 0xff   
write_key[14] :: 0xff   
write_key[15] :: 0xff
```

Which is as expected. 
but when i cross compiled this program for Mips based embedded board and run it there my output is.

```
write_key[0] :: 0x7f   
write_key[1] :: 0xff   
write_key[2] :: 0xff   
write_key[3] :: 0xff   
write_key[4] :: 0x7f   
write_key[5] :: 0xff   
write_key[6] :: 0xff   
write_key[7] :: 0xff   
write_key[8] :: 0x7f   
write_key[9] :: 0xff   
write_key[10] :: 0xff   
write_key[11] :: 0xff   
write_key[12] :: 0x7f   
write_key[13] :: 0xff   
write_key[14] :: 0xff   
write_key[15] :: 0xff
```

Why there is a difference in output for different architecture ?

Comment: Have you done any debugging? For example, what does `strtol("ffffffff", NULL, 16)` return on the two platforms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strtol` returns a `long int`. If `long int` is 32 bits wide on on your platform, then it can't represent `0xffffffff` (which is about 4 billion).

[man strtol](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html#RETURN_VALUE):

> The `strtol()` function returns the result of the conversion, unless
>          the value would underflow or overflow.  If an underflow occurs,
>          `strtol()` returns `LONG_MIN`.  If an overflow occurs, `strtol()` returns
>          `LONG_MAX`.

So it returns `LONG_MAX`, which in 32 bits is `0x7fffffff` (or about 2 billion), because that's the biggest positive 32-bit number.

Presumably your Linux PC uses 64-bit `long int`s so this problem doesn't occur there.

To fix this problem, change the code to use `strtoul`, because `0xffffffff` fits just fine into an `unsigned long int`.

Answer (score 3):

`strtol` returns a long, possibly a 32 bit integer, signed. It ranges from -1 (`0xFFFFFFFF`) to `0x7FFFFFFF`.

The shifting may behave differently on negative numbers depending on the compiler as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39853049/implementation-of-logical-right-shift-of-negative-numbers-in-c) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009885/arithmetic-bit-shift-on-a-signed-integer) (Right-shifting negative numbers invoke implementation-defined behavior in C)

That's probably why you have the problem: EDIT: I was right about the *probably* :), After melponeme comment, I just tested the result of `strtol("0xffffffff)` on a 32-bit compiler and it returns `0x7FFFFFFF`, so the problem is not the shifting.

What I'm sure will solve your problem, is that switching to `strtoul` to return unsigned long will do the trick: it will return an unsigned long (first problem solved) and it will be sure that the shifting will work as you want.

As a final note, I would recommend that you use a 32-bit compiler on your Linux machine (even if the machine is 64-bit) so you're closer to your target architecture and you'll detect problems like that earlier.

Comment: Here's the reference you were looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009885/arithmetic-bit-shift-on-a-signed-integer

Comment: yeah got that one too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39853049/implementation-of-logical-right-shift-of-negative-numbers-in-c: "right shifting negative numbers is implementation dependent"

Comment: Yeah, but it has no answers with standard references, which I feel is better at driving the point home.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with shifting negative numbers. `strtol` returns a positive result for positive inputs.

Comment: @melpomene: you're right. Just tested it on a 32-bit compiler. I have edited my answer for the sake of correctness. But after that you could have UB on the shifting. So the strtoul solution works.